# Excel Column Filter grouped period delimited like dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-filter

In Excel I'm searching for a way to filter a table/column head filter with cells with content like: `1`, `1.1`, `1.2`, etc in a grouped manner like it does with dates:

> - 2022
>
>   - 09
>
>     - 20
>     - 21
>   - 10
>
>     - 01
>     - 02

So, the expected filter should look something like:

> - 1
>
>   - 1
>   - 2
>   - 3
>
>     - 1
>   - 4
> - 2

I don't want to use VBA. I assume this is a rather common filtering

Answer (score 0):

Excel has two ways to create a collapsible structure for your data (not exactly a filter but I think this will work for you).

1. Try Data > Group > Group...
2. Or, create a pivot table from you data

Both these methods create expandable/collapsible trees to hide subordinant data. I've never liked the way Excel implemented #1 as it always felt like the plus / minus buttons are on the wrong row, but hey, it works.

Comment: Hi @ExcelEverything, I also want to filter on another column, using groups makes that impossible. I am not sure a pivot table can work. I'm creating/editing this workbook that serves as a gantt planner, which uses a lot of conditional markups. If I'm not mistaking, that's not possible with pivot tables, correct?

Comment: Ah I think I only now understand what you are really asking. Do you want your numbered list to group together in the auto-filter drop down list (like dates group together as months / years)? I don't think this can be done, even in VBA. At best you can use groups as described above together with another auto-filter column (they work together, but first apply the auto-filter, then collapse the group & reapply the auto-filter after expanding the group). Alternatively, make sure your numbered list is *text* (i.e. place ' in front `'1.1.0`), then use text filters in the auto-filter like `1.*`.

Comment: The alternative way seems to be to be the way to go. I find it quite sad that Excel doesn't have the feature.  Thanks for the sparring!